# Авторасстановка флажков в гугл форме

Tags: javascript, python

Имеется голосовалка в гугл форме, на которой нужно регулярно расставлять чекбоксы. Хочу это дело автоматизировать, каким образом можно это организовать? Пока я думаю использовать библиотеку pyAutoGui на python сделать открытие страницы и заполнение нужных чекбоксов. Капча вручную. Какие есть еще варианты? Возможно ли на js сделать скрипт, который лезет на гугл форму по адресу и расставляет чекбоксы?
(Уровень новичок, постарайтесь ответить с небольшими пояснениями)

Comment: И что Вы хотите услышать в ответ на свой поток сознания? Выберите способ, попытайтесь его реализовать, и приходите сюда с конкретным кодом, если не получится заставить его работать.

Comment: На JS есть [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer), для него уже написаны готовые модули для решения капчи разных видов. Для Python есть [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/)

Comment: Уже начал делать на селениум, но на будущее почитаю что такое Puppeteer. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону библиотеки [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/). В ней существует возможность эмулировать действия браузера через Python.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import static org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated;
import java.time.Duration;

public class HelloSelenium {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        try {
            driver.get("https://google.com/ncr");
            driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("cheese" + Keys.ENTER);
            WebElement firstResult = wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("h3>div")));
            System.out.println(firstResult.getAttribute("textContent"));
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как раз селениум нагуглить успел, думаю это то, что мне нужно, спасибо за пример.